# Count dates that have a certain day per month and year

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot the dates that have a certain day, such that different dates with the same date are counted separately. For example, I write the following:

```
dates <-  c("2018-01-03", "2018-01-17", "2018-02-03", "2018-02-03", "2018-02-16", 
            "2018-02-26", "2018-03-03")
data <- as.data.frame(dates)

ggplot(data) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = day(dates)), 
           stat = "count")
```

However, this gives me 4 day 3, 1 day 16, 1 day 17 and 1 day 26 (see picture). However, what I want to get is:
for 2018-01: 1 day 3 and 1 day 17
for 2018-02: 2 day 3, 1 day 16 and 1 day 26
for 2018-03: 1 day 3

I do not know whether I was clear eonugh
[image]

Comment: You have used incorrect function here i.e. day() that's why it has been shown on x-axis day-wise

Comment: Yes, that is the point. Is there another way (function) to achieve what I want?

Comment: See the solution, perhaps I have understood you correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can produce the barplot you are looking for by using `table`:

```
as.data.frame(table(dates)) %>% 
    ggplot() + geom_bar(aes(x=dates, y=Freq), stat="identity")
```

[image]

Or, a little cleaner:

```
as.data.frame(table(dates)) %>% 
    ggplot() + geom_bar(aes(x=dates, y=Freq, fill=month(dates)), stat="identity")
```

[image]

Comment: I think the solution actually was using stat_count
 

ggplot(data) +
  stat_count(aes(x = (birthday)))

Answer (score 0):

Or probably you are looking for this? (I'm not sure)

```
data %>%mutate(dates = as.Date(dates)) %>% group_by(dates) %>% summarise(Freq = n()) %>%
  ggplot() + geom_col(aes(x=dates, y=Freq, fill = Freq)) +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%m-%d")
```

Output

[image]